# Array items to html with br

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, line, break

```
var clubs = ['Ajax', 'PSV', 'Feyenoord', 'NAC', 'FC Twente', 'FC Groningen', 'FC Utrecht'];
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var counter = 0;
document.getElementById('eredivisie').innerHTML = clubs;

function extraClubs () {
    if (counter == 1) {
        document.getElementById('eredivisie').disabled = true;  
    } else {
    clubs.push('Excelsior', 'Sparta', 'Vitesse');
    document.getElementById('eredivisie').innerHTML = clubs;
    counter++;
    }
};
add.addEventListener('click', extraClubs);
```

I have an array with some Dutch football clubs and the function to add some football clubs to the array when a button is pressed. Both works fine. In the HTML it  shows like this :

Ajax,PSV,Feyenoord,NAC,FC Twente,FC Groningen,FC Utrecht,Excelsior,Sparta,Vitesse

How can I fix that the each item in the array will start on a new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line, clubs is converted to a string:

```
  document.getElementById('eredivisie').innerHTML = clubs;
```

So js will do this for you:

```
 clubs.toString()
```

and that is equal to:

```
 clubs.join(",")
```

To now achieve the desired result instead, we need to join the array with a newline:

```
  clubs.join("<br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Will add a break after each item.

```
clubs.join("<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the function `map` to wrap your teams with `<p>team</p>`.
- Then, you need to join the mapped elements using the function `join`.

```js
var clubs = ['Ajax', 'PSV', 'Feyenoord', 'NAC', 'FC Twente', 'FC Groningen', 'FC Utrecht'];
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var counter = 0;
document.getElementById('eredivisie').innerHTML = clubs.map(s => '<p>' + s + '</p>').join('');

function extraClubs() {
  if (counter == 1) {
    document.getElementById('eredivisie').disabled = true;
  } else {
    clubs.push('Excelsior', 'Sparta', 'Vitesse');
    document.getElementById('eredivisie').innerHTML = clubs.map(s => '<p>' + s + '</p>').join('');
    counter++;
  }
};
add.addEventListener('click', extraClubs);
```

```html
<button id="add"> ADD </button>
<p></p>
<div id="eredivisie"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript to create and append new [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) for each array item. This is create a new line by default.

```
//first clear old innerHTML then
var myText = document.createTextNode(item[i]);
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.appendChild(myText);
document.appendChild(myDiv)
```